# Why I Should Clean & Build My C# Console Project In VsCode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, console-application

I have a dotnet 7.0 c# console project for my Migration layer and the problem is that I should clean and build my project as I do some changes in it.
If I didn't do that my changes does not execute.

I try in Visual Studio and it works properly

Comment: [Generate tasks.json and launch.json to build and debug the .NET web app](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/06/24/vs-code-net-debug-a-net-web-app-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Are you on MacOS? Why are you using vscode for c#?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could prepare steps to reproduce the problem you are having.  (Often this exercise alone can be enough to improve your understanding of the issue.)

Comment: I prefer use vscode, It's Lighter @SupaMaggie70b

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my launch.jason file and in my console project configurations i used  `"preLaunchTask": "build"` and I had this tag in my task.json file for "build"

```
{
        "label": "build",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "process",
        "args": [
            "build",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Cooking.RestApi/Cooking.RestApi.csproj",
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
```

As you see this is for my RestApi layer and I create new task like below for my console app

```
{
        "label": "build-migration",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "process",
        "args": [
            "build",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Cooking.Migrations/Cooking.Migrations.csproj",
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
```

And finally I put it in my lunch.jason file, like this:

```
{
        "name": "Migrations",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build-migration",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Cooking.Migrations/bin/Debug/net7.0/Cooking.Migrations.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Cooking.Migrations",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "console": "internalConsole"
    }
```